# How can I hatch the areas delimited by two intersecting Gaussian distribution curves?

Tags: pgfplots

This is a follow-up to one of my earlier questions: [Fill area between curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161862/fill-area-between-curves).

I want to color three regions delimited by two curves and a vertical line. Each should have its own shading and color. The problem is that, no matter what I do, I still don't get it right.

1. First area is from the leftmost to the vertical line below the left curve. The abscissa for the vertical bar should be 6.
2. Second area should be the common area below two curves delimited on the right by the vertical bar.
3. Third area is delimited above by the right curve, below the left curve and by the right bar.

The image below shows the output I expect:
[image]

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{dnorm}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1.5:12,samples=101,height=8cm,width=12cm, xticklabel=\empty,
    yticklabel=\empty]



\addplot [fill=yellow,draw=none,domain=-1:6,stack plots=y] {max(dnorm(3,1.5)-dnorm(6,1.5),0) } \closedcycle;

\addplot [draw=none,pattern=north west lines,pattern color=orange,domain=-1.5:6,stack plots=y] {min(dnorm(3,1.5),dnorm(6.5,1.5)) } \closedcycle;


\addplot [draw=none,pattern=grid,pattern color=gray,domain=-1.5:6,stack plots=y] {max( dnorm(6,1.5) - dnorm(3,1.5),0)} \closedcycle;


% Draw curves
\addplot [thin, smooth, color=black] {dnorm(3,1.5)};
\addplot [thin, smooth, color=black] {dnorm(6,1.5)};

% Draw vertical bar:
\draw [red, thick] ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:6,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1}-|{axis cs:6,0});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your description (specially points 2 and three) confuses me a little. Can you please make a hand-made drawing of the three regions you want to fill?

Comment: I am currently working on pgfplots 1.10 which will contain a systematic and simple approach to fill areas between plots. Would you mind if I take your example into the pgfplots manual?

Comment: This is used as an example in Section 5.6.6 Intersection Segment Recombination of the `pgfplots` 1.11 manual.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure if these are the regions you are trying to fill, so I will fill all of them and then you can choose which ones do you need:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{dnorm}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  domain=-1:12,
  samples=101,
  height=8cm,
  width=12cm, 
  xticklabel=\empty,
  yticklabel=\empty]

\addplot[
  fill=yellow,
  draw=none,
  domain=-1:6,
  stack plots=y
  ] 
  {dnorm(3,1.5)} \closedcycle;

\addplot [
    fill=orange,
    draw=none,
    domain=-1:6,
    stack plots=y
] {min( dnorm(6,1.5) - dnorm(3,1.5),0)} \closedcycle;

\addplot [
    fill=cyan,
    draw=none,
    domain=-1:6,
    stack plots=y
] {max( dnorm(6,1.5) - dnorm(3,1.5),0)} \closedcycle;

\addplot [
    fill=magenta,
    draw=none,
    domain=6:12,
] {max( dnorm(6,1.5),dnorm(3,1.5))} \closedcycle;

\addplot [
    fill=olive,
    draw=none,
    domain=6:12,
] {min( dnorm(6,1.5),dnorm(3,1.5))} \closedcycle;

% Draw curves
\addplot [thin, smooth, color=black] {dnorm(3,1.5)};
\addplot [thin, smooth, color=black] {dnorm(6,1.5)};

% Draw vertical bar:
\draw [red, thick] ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:6,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1}-|{axis cs:6,0});
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I acknowledge that my question was a little bit confusing. I needed to color exactly the orange area, the yellow and the cyan one. I must admit however that I'm still missing the sequence I have to use to color the areas without one overlapping the other. I'll post my final answer below.

ps: how do you post the figure in your answer? Is there any hidden compiler or sth?

Comment: @Chedly to add an image, on Linux I use Okular as pDF viewer; I can then select the designated area and save the image as a PNG image whivh then I upload using the functionality provided by the site (the button with an image icon that appears on top of the editing window when you campose/edit a question/answer). In Windows I use GreenShot to do basically the same.

Answer (score 10):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-func`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-func) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-func}
\usepackage{xfp}

% function
\def\Gauss[#1,#2]#3{\fpeval{1/(sqrt(2*pi)*#2)*exp(-(#3-#1)^2/(2*#2^2))}}

% settings for PSTricks
\psset{
  xunit = 2,
  yunit = 3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.25,-0.15)(4.8,1.8)
% parameters
\def\mueA{2}
\def\mueB{2.7}
\def\sigma{0.4}
% points on curve
\def\pointA{2.1}
\def\pointB{3.1}
  % drawing
  \psaxes[labels = none, ticks = none]{->}(0,0)(4.8,1.8)
  \uput[270](2.4,0){\small Internal Response (a.u.)}
  \rput(0.3,0.7){\psrotate(0,0){90}{\small Probability}}
  \psGauss[mue = \mueA, sigma = \sigma]{0.5}{3.5}
  \pscustom[fillstyle = hlines, hatchsep = 2pt]{%
    \psGauss[mue = \mueB, sigma = \sigma, hatchsep = 1pt]{2.2}{4.4}
    \psline(2.2,0)(2.2,1)}
  \pscustom[fillstyle = vlines]{%
    \psline(2.2,1)(2.2,0)
    \psGauss[mue = \mueB, sigma = \sigma]{0}{2.2}}
  \psline[linewidth = 1.5pt](2.2,0)(2.2,1.3)
  \uput[90](2.2,1.3){\small criterion respons}
  \psline{->}(\fpeval{\pointA-0.3},\fpeval{\Gauss[\mueB,\sigma]{\pointA}+0.2})(\pointA,\Gauss[\mueB,\sigma]{\pointA})
  \uput[90](  \fpeval{\pointA-0.3},\fpeval{\Gauss[\mueB,\sigma]{\pointA}+0.2}){\footnotesize Miss}
  \psline{->}(\fpeval{\pointB+0.3},\fpeval{\Gauss[\mueB,\sigma]{\pointB}+0.2})(\pointB,\Gauss[\mueB,\sigma]{\pointB})
  \uput[90](  \fpeval{\pointB+0.3},\fpeval{\Gauss[\mueB,\sigma]{\pointB}+0.2}){\footnotesize Hit}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.25,-0.15)(4.8,1.8)
% parameters
\def\mueA{2}
\def\mueB{2.7}
\def\sigma{0.4}
% points on curve
\def\pointA{1.6}
\def\pointB{2.8}
  % drawing
  \psaxes[labels = none, ticks = none]{->}(0,0)(4.8,1.8)
  \uput[270](2.4,0){\small Internal Response (a.u.)}
  \rput(0.3,0.7){\psrotate(0,0){90}{\small Probability}}
  \psGauss[mue = \mueB, sigma = \sigma]{0.5}{4.5}
  \pscustom[fillstyle = hlines, hatchsep = 2pt]{%
    \psGauss[mue = \mueA, sigma = \sigma, hatchsep = 1pt]{2.2}{4.4}
    \psline(2.2,0)(2.2,1)}
  \pscustom[fillstyle = vlines]{%
    \psline(2.2,1)(2.2,0)
    \psGauss[mue = \mueA, sigma = \sigma]{0}{2.2}}
  \psline[linewidth = 1.5pt](2.2,0)(2.2,1.3)
  \uput[90](2.2,1.3){\small criterion respons}
  \psline{->}(\fpeval{\pointA-0.3},\fpeval{\Gauss[\mueA,\sigma]{\pointA}+0.2})(\pointA,\Gauss[\mueA,\sigma]{\pointA})
  \uput[120](\fpeval{\pointA-0.3},\fpeval{\Gauss[\mueA,\sigma]{\pointA}+0.2}){\footnotesize Correct rejection}
  \psline{->}(\fpeval{\pointB+0.3},\fpeval{\Gauss[\mueA,\sigma]{\pointB}+0.2})(\pointB,\Gauss[\mueA,\sigma]{\pointB})
  \uput[90](\fpeval{\pointB+0.3},\fpeval{\Gauss[\mueA,\sigma]{\pointB}+0.2}){\footnotesize False alarm}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that you can easily change the position of the arrows pointing on the curve simply by changing the values of `\pointA` and `\pointB`, respectively.

Answer (score 8):

Version 1.10 of pgfplots has been released just recently, and it comes with a new solution for the problem to fill the area between plots.

Note that the old solution is still possible and still valid; this here is merely an update which might simplify the task. In order to keep the knowledge base of this site up-to-date, I present a solution based on the new `fillbetween` library here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

% \usetikzlibrary{}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{dnorm}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-3:12,samples=25,height=8cm,width=12cm]

    % Draw curves
    \addplot [name path=g3,thin, smooth, color=black] {dnorm(3,1.5)};
    \addplot [name path=g6,thin, smooth, color=black] {dnorm(6,1.5)};

    % Draw vertical bar:
    \draw [name path=red,red, thick] ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:6,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1}-|{axis cs:6,0});


    \addplot fill between[of=g3 and g6,
        soft clip={domain=-6:6},
        split,
        every segment no 0/.style={yellow},
        every segment no 1/.style={pattern=grid,pattern color=gray},
    ];

    \path[name path=lower,
        %draw=red,ultra thick,
        intersection segments={
            of=g3 and g6,
            sequence=B0 -- A1
        }
    ];
    \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:-10,0) -- (axis cs:16,0);

    \addplot[pattern=north west lines,
        pattern color=orange]
    fill between[
        of=axis and lower,
        soft clip={domain=-6:6}]
    ;

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This solution labels the two involved input plots by `g3` and `g6`, respectively. The third `\addplot` command makes uses of the new `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}`: it computes the filled region between `g3 and g6`. In addition, it clips the result to `domain=-6:6` ("soft clip" is quite similar to standard clipping, but tailored for this use-case and with a simplified syntax). Consequently, everything right of x=6 is not part of the filled region. The key `split` means that the filled region should be split into individual segment, and each segment can receive an individual style. In our case, we assign segment styles for the 0st and 1st segment to be `yellow` and a pattern, respectively.

The following `\path` instruction computes (but does not `draw`) the part *below* the intersection. It does so by means of the new feature `intersection segments` which is also part of `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}`. In this case, the intersection segments consists of `B0` which is the first (0th) segment of the second argument of `g3 and g6`, in other words: the first intersection segment of `g6`. It connects this part with `A1` which is the second (1st) part of the first argument of `of=g3 and g6`. This result is not drawn and not filled; it is merely associated with the name `lower`.

The `\path[name path=axis]` simply assigns a name a path of the x axis.

Finally, the last `\addplot fill between` fills the region between the `axis` and `lower` and fills it with a pattern. Note that this `fill between` also has a `soft clip` path which restricts its region to `x=-6:6`.

Comment: A valuable update Christian.

Answer (score 2):

This is my final answer:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{dnorm}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-3:12,samples=101,height=8cm,width=12cm]

    \addplot [draw=none,pattern=north west lines,pattern color=orange,domain=-3:6,stack plots=y] {dnorm(3,1.5)} \closedcycle;

    \addplot [fill=yellow,draw=none,domain=-3:6,stack plots=y] {min(dnorm(6,1.5)-dnorm(3,1.5),0) } \closedcycle;

    \addplot [draw=none,pattern=grid,pattern color=gray,domain=-3:6,stack plots=y] {max( dnorm(6,1.5) - dnorm(3,1.5),0)} \closedcycle;

    % Draw curves
    \addplot [thin, smooth, color=black] {dnorm(3,1.5)};
    \addplot [thin, smooth, color=black] {dnorm(6,1.5)};

    % Draw vertical bar:
    \draw [red, thick] ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:6,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1}-|{axis cs:6,0});

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I uploaded the image for you. I hope it's OK.