# Shade region where two Gaussians overlap

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to shade the region where the two Gaussians overlap.

My code is as follows (altered from Christian's answer here: [How can I hatch the areas delimited by two intersecting Gaussian distribution curves?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162438/how-can-i-hatch-the-areas-delimited-by-two-intersecting-gaussian-distribution-cu)):

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:10,samples=100,height=6cm,width=10cm, ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty]

% Draw gaussians                                                                                                                                            
\addplot [name path=model,very thick, smooth, color=red!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
\addplot [name path=obs,very thick, smooth, color=black] {gauss(5,1.5)};

% calculate region to shade                                                                                                                                   
\path[name path=lower,
intersection segments={
of=model and obs,
sequence=A0 -- B1
}
];
\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:-10,0) -- (axis cs:16,0);

% shade region                                                                                                                                                
\addplot[color=red!20!gray!20]
fill between[
of=axis and lower,
soft clip={domain=1:10}]
;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Attempting to shade region where two Gaussians overlap]

Thanks,
Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have to add the segment `A2` to `sequence`:

```
sequence=A0 -- B1 -- A2
```

Or you use the newer version of the syntax:

```
sequence={L1 -- R2 --L3}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}
  {\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=0:10,samples=100,
  height=6cm,width=10cm,
  ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,
  every axis plot/.append style={very thick,smooth}
]

\addplot [name path=model, color=red!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
\addplot [name path=obs, color=black] {gauss(5,1.5)};
\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:10,0);

\path[name path=lower,
  intersection segments={of=model and obs,
    sequence={L1 -- R2 --L3}
  }];
\addplot[color=red!20!gray!20]
  fill between[of= lower and axis];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is an additional picture that shows the used segements `L1` (orange), `R2` (blue) and `L2` (green):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}
  {\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=0:10,samples=100,
  height=6cm,width=10cm,
  ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,
  every axis plot/.append style={very thick,smooth}
]

\addplot [name path=model, color=red!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
\addplot [name path=obs, color=black] {gauss(5,1.5)};
\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:10,0);


\path[draw,orange,line width=1mm,
  intersection segments={of=model and obs,
    sequence={L1}
  }];

\path[draw,blue,line width=1mm,
  intersection segments={of=model and obs,
    sequence={R2}
  }];


\path[draw,green,line width=1mm,
  intersection segments={of=model and obs,
    sequence={L3}
  }];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (not so great) solution/workaround.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:10,samples=100,height=6cm,width=10cm, ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty]

\addplot [name path=model,very thick, smooth, color=red!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
\addplot [name path=obs,very thick, smooth, color=black] {gauss(5,1.5)};

\path[name path=lower,
intersection segments={
of=model and obs,
sequence=A0 -- B1
}
];
\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:-10,0) -- (axis cs:16,0);

\addplot[color=red!20!gray!20]
fill between[
of= model and axis]
;
\addplot[color=white]
fill between[
of=model and obs,
soft clip={domain=1:10}]
;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]