# Plotting a closed parametric curve and shading the area inside it

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, graphs

I wish to plot the curve defined by the parametric equations x = 1+sin t,y = 3 + 3(cos t)^3, such that the region bounded by this curve is shaded. As far as the code goes, I can't seem to find a similar example online to help me, so I don't have a starting point to work from. Any help plotting this curve would be much appreciated. I would like a basic set of axes to go with it, labelled x and y with an O to mark the origin.

Comment: Parametric plots are pretty easy with pgfplots (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280595/plotting-the-graph-for-expcos1-x/280607?s=1|27.1801#280607 for examploe).  [fill between] is typically done between two plots (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195098/fill-between-two-plots) although one could always be creative (see page 432 of the pgfplots manual).

Answer (score 3):

Error corrected, thanks to Franck Pastor!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[-latex] (0,0) node[left] {$O$}-- (3,0) node[below]{$x$};
 \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[left]{$y$};
 \clip plot[smooth,samples=36,domain=0:360,variable=\t] ({1+sin(\t)},{3 + 3*(cos
 (\t))^3});
 \draw[fill=blue,opacity=0.8] (0,0) rectangle (2,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How come that half of the curve is below the x-axis ? `y = 3+3(cos t)^3` is always positive… Am I missing something?

Comment: @FranckPastor That's a very good point!

Comment: What does the option `[-latex]` do to the `\draw` commands?

Comment: @AnnieCarter It adds an arrow head of the `latex` type, which looks arguably nicer than what you get with `->`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way without using `\clip` is the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] plot[smooth,domain=-90:90,variable=\t] ({1+sin(\t)},{3 + 3(cos \t)^3}) 
            plot[smooth,domain=90:270,variable=\t] ({1+sin(\t)},{3 + 3(cos \t)^3});
\draw[-latex] (0,0) node[left] {$O$}-- (3,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[left]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Same question as for Marmot: How come that half of this curve is below the x-axis ? y = 3+3(cos t)^3 is always positive.

Comment: The problem is that the `3(cos \t)^3` that appears in each coordinate doesn't get parsed correctly. This can be fixed by making the multiplication explicit: `3*(cos \t)^3`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try with MetaPost, inserted in a LuaLaTeX program for convenience. With MetaPost, the parametric curve can be closed and then filled by making it a cycle (`.. cycle` instruction), right as it's about to join itself.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
u := cm; xmax = 2.25; ymax = 6.25;
vardef f(expr t) = 1 + sind t enddef;
vardef g(expr t) = 3 + 3((cosd t)**3) enddef;
path curve;
beginfig(1); 
    % Axes and Labels
    drawarrow origin -- (xmax*u, 0);
    label.llft(btex $O$ etex, origin); 
    label.bot(btex $x$ etex, (xmax*u, 0));
    drawarrow origin -- (0, ymax*u);
    label.lft(btex $y$ etex, (0, ymax*u));
    % Filled Curve
    curve = ((f(0), g(0)) for t = 1 upto 359: .. (f(t), g(t)) endfor .. cycle) scaled u;
    fill curve withcolor blue;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very slight variation on [user's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410551/21607) which doesn't require finding coordinates for the shaded region:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[-latex] (0,0) node[left] {$O$}-- (3,0) node[below]{$x$};
 \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[left]{$y$};
 \begin{scope}[fill=blue,opacity=0.8]
  \fill[clip] plot[smooth,samples=36,domain=0:360,variable=\t] ({1+sin(\t)},{3 + 3*(cos
 (\t))^3});
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another way to doing it using `\filldraw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[-latex] (0,0) node[left] {$O$}-- (3,0) node[below]{$x$};
 \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[left]{$y$};
 \filldraw[blue!80] plot[smooth,samples=36,domain=0:360,variable=\t] ({1+sin(\t)},{3 + 3*(cos
 (\t))^3});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few years late! A solution with lualatex : tkz packages are not required[image] ...

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-elements}
\begin{document}

\begin{tkzelements}
function fun (t)
  return 1+math.sin(t)
  end
function gun (t)
 return 3 + 3*(math.cos(t))^3
 end 

 function f(t0, t1, n)
     local dt = (t1-t0)/n 
     local t = t0
     local out=assert(io.open("tmp.table","w"))
     local x,y
     while (t <= t1) do
       x = fun(t)
       y = gun(t)
       out:write(x, " ", y, " i\string\n") 
       t = t + dt
     end
     out:close()
 end
\end{tkzelements}

\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=6]
\tkzDrawX \tkzDrawY
\directlua{f(0,2*math.pi,100)}
\filldraw[thick,top color =blue!40] plot[smooth] file {tmp.table};
\draw[thick,blue] plot[smooth] file {tmp.table};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```