# Error bars as shaded area

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, error-bars

I'm wondering if there is a possibility for Latex to display the error bars of a curve or series of data points as a shaded area rather than individual bars on the points; something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957582/plot-yerr-xerr-as-shaded-region-rather-than-error-bars). I browsed through the pgfplots manual and found nothing of the sorts.

My idea so far is to plot the y-error and y+error as solids and fill the space between both of them, as is done in [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161862/fill-area-between-curves#161870).

An example of what I mean: the top image has regular error bars, and the bottom image has error bars as a shaded area (done with Python according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957582/plot-yerr-xerr-as-shaded-region-rather-than-error-bars).

[image: Plot with regular error bars]
[image: Plot with error bars as shaded area]

Comment: Instead of just referencing the questions form where you got the ideas, please include also a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have so far.

Comment: Is your error relative (e.g. +/- 10%) or given as a separate column in a table? You can do that with the `fillbetween` library, plot y+error and y-error as separate plots, use `fill between` to fill the area between them.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. my error is given as a separate column in a table. Is fill between part of a specific package? I searched for it in Miktex's MPM and I found nothing

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a library included with `pgfplots`, see the "Related libraries" part in the `pgfplots` manual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick example with `pgfplots` and the `fillbetween` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y err
0 1 0.1
1 1.5 0.3
2 2 0.2
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[x=x,y=y] {data.dat};

\addplot [name path=upper,draw=none] table[x=x,y expr=\thisrow{y}+\thisrow{err}] {data.dat};
\addplot [name path=lower,draw=none] table[x=x,y expr=\thisrow{y}-\thisrow{err}] {data.dat};
\addplot [fill=blue!10] fill between[of=upper and lower];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that I had a pgfplots manual from 2010 and couldn't find the fill between part in the Related libraries. It blows my mind that now pgfplots can work with units as well.