# Newcommand and macro expansion in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I would like to create a shaded error bar area such as in [Error bars as shaded area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430650/error-bars-as-shaded-area).
To avoid copy pasting the same code over several pgfplots figure, I try to make a new command which do this automatically.

I succeeded to draw the area with the example below, but I hit a problem with macro expansion : the macro which define the color is expanded only at the end and so my two plots have the same color.

I tried several techniques : using `\edef`, several `\expandafter`, using `key/.expanded`. But I always get the same color.

Is there a way to correctly expand my \fillcolor macro ? Or a cleaner way to do what I want ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\tikzset{test/.style={
    draw/.expanded={#1},
    fill/.expanded={#1!50}
}}

\pgfplotstableset{
  y name/.estore in=\yname, 
  y err name/.estore in=\yerrname, 
  fcolor/.estore in=\fillcolor,
}

\newcommand{\adderrorzone}[2][]{
  \pgfplotstableset{#1}


  \addplot[test=\expandafter\fillcolor] table[#1, y=\yname] {#2};
  \addlegendentryexpanded{\fillcolor}

  \addplot[name path=upper2, draw=none, forget plot] table[y expr=(\thisrow{\yname} + \thisrow{\yerrname})] {#2};
  \addplot[name path=lower2, draw=none, forget plot] table[y expr=(\thisrow{\yname} - \thisrow{\yerrname})] {#2};
 
  \addplot[test=\fillcolor, semitransparent, forget plot, draw=none] fill between[of=upper2 and lower2];
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
x   y   yerr
0   1   .5
1   3   1
}\tableA

\pgfplotstableread{
x   y   yerr
0   4   .5
1   5   .2
}\tableB

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \adderrorzone[x=x, y name=y, y err name=yerr, fcolor=blue] {\tableA};
      \adderrorzone[x=x, y name=y, y err name=yerr, fcolor=red] {\tableB};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result : [image: Exemple of MWE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that, no matter how one does, `\fillcolor` is stored unexpanded.

Perhaps there are better ways, but this works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\tikzset{
  test/.style={
    draw={#1},
    fill={#1!50},
  },
}

\pgfplotstableset{
  y name/.estore in=\yname, 
  y err name/.estore in=\yerrname, 
  fcolor/.estore in=\fillcolor,
}

\newcommand{\adderrorzone}[2][]{
  \pgfplotstableset{#1}
  \expanded{\noexpand\addplot[test=\fillcolor]} table[#1, y=\yname] {#2};
  \expanded{\noexpand\addlegendentryexpanded{\fillcolor}}
  \addplot[
    name path=upper2,
    draw=none,
    forget plot,
  ] table[y expr=(\thisrow{\yname} + \thisrow{\yerrname})] {#2};
  \addplot[
    name path=lower2,
    draw=none,
    forget plot
  ] table[y expr=(\thisrow{\yname} - \thisrow{\yerrname})] {#2};
  \expanded{\noexpand\addplot[
    test=\fillcolor,
    semitransparent,
    draw=none,
    forget plot,
  ]} fill between[of=upper2 and lower2];
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
x   y   yerr
0   1   .5
1   3   1
}\tableA

\pgfplotstableread{
x   y   yerr
0   4   .5
1   5   .2
}\tableB

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \adderrorzone[x=x, y name=y, y err name=yerr, fcolor=blue] {\tableA}
    \adderrorzone[x=x, y name=y, y err name=yerr, fcolor=red] {\tableB}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You may want to move the legend…

[image]

Comment: Well, the trick does the job, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By giving the color with a parameter rather than by a command. (There is surely a better solution):
`\adderrorzone[x=x, y name=y, y err name=yerr] {\tableA}{blue};`

- the last version of pgfplots is 1.18
- `.expanded` is not necessary

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}%-<-- load tikz
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%<-- last version
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\tikzset{
  test/.style={
    draw={#1},%<-- modif
    fill={#1!50},%<-- modif
  },
}

\pgfplotstableset{
  y name/.estore in=\yname, 
  y err name/.estore in=\yerrname, 
  % fcolor/.estore in=#3,
}

\newcommand{\adderrorzone}[3][]{
\pgfplotstableset{#1}

\addplot[test=#3] table[#1, y=\yname] {#2};
\addlegendentryexpanded{#3}

\addplot[name path=upper2, draw=none, forget plot] table[y expr=(\thisrow{\yname} + \thisrow{\yerrname})] {#2};
\addplot[name path=lower2, draw=none, forget plot] table[y expr=(\thisrow{\yname} - \thisrow{\yerrname})] {#2};

\addplot[test=#3,semitransparent, forget plot, draw=none] fill between[of=upper2 and lower2];
}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  x   y   yerr
  0   1   .5
  1   3   1
}\tableA

\pgfplotstableread{
  x   y   yerr
  0   4   .5
  1   5   .2
}\tableB

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \adderrorzone[x=x, y name=y, y err name=yerr] {\tableA}{blue};
    \adderrorzone[x=x, y name=y, y err name=yerr] {\tableB}{red};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]