How to draw this sort of diagram: Line plot with vertical error indicator
I want to plot this diagram in LaTeX:

I need ranges in x and y at the same time. I want to show Global Warming Impact (GWI) over Net Present Value (NPV) for different scenarios of both indicators. Practically a combined econonmic and envrionmental plot of four different products (A,B,C,D). The values are calculated theoretically. The plot is supposed to show how profitable the products are and what their global warming impacts are in their sensitivity ranges - together in one plot.
This is the code I used to manually plot the values:
 \documentclass{scrbook}   
    \usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                extra x ticks       = 0,
                extra x tick labels = ,
                extra x tick style  = { grid = major },
                height=7cm,
                width=14cm,
                ylabel=GWI,
                xlabel=NPV,
                legend pos=outer north east,
                ]               
                \addplot[CornflowerBlue,mark=*,line width=1pt] plot[error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,y explicit,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                error mark options={
                    rotate=90,
                    mark size=2pt,
                    line width=1pt}
                ]
                coordinates {
                    (-24.8,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (-19.0,9.34)+= (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7) 
                    (-15.3,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (218.4,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7) 
                    (275.3,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (309.7,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (510.8,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (629.0,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (700.4,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                };
                \addlegendentry{A}
                \addplot[YellowGreen,mark=*,line width=1pt] plot[error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,y explicit,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                error mark options={
                    rotate=90,
                    mark size=2pt,
                    line width=1pt}
                ]
                coordinates {
                    (-154.1,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (-152.6,16.76) +-(0,2.2) 
                    (-149.4,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (93.80,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (141.7,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (170.9,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (386.2,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (495.4,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (561.6,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                };
                \addlegendentry{B}              
                \addplot[Goldenrod, mark=*,line width=1pt] plot[error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,y explicit,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                error mark options={
                    rotate=90,
                    mark size=2pt,
                    line width=1pt}
                ]
                coordinates {
                    (-204.9,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (-194.5,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0) 
                    (-176.9,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (66.40,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0) 
                    (99.80,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (120.2,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (358.8,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (453.5,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (510.8,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                };          
                \addlegendentry{C}
                \addplot[Lavender,mark=*,line width=1pt] plot[error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,y explicit,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                error mark options={
                    rotate=90,
                    mark size=2pt,
                    line width=1pt}
                ]
                coordinates {
                    (-109.6,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (-108.0,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8) 
                    (-105.0,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (138.3,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8) 
                    (186.3,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (215.5,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (430.6,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (540.0,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (606.1,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                };
                \addlegendentry{D}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


TikZ is the goto graphics making program for many in this site.  I would have a start there.  Even if you're not able to find macros that make what you want, you'd be able to hand specify the individual lines.

Yes, TikZ is definitely what I want to use... but I don´t know how to set up the data  so that these ranges appear exaclty like that, even when doing everything by hand.

Could you make a first attempt that gets some of the pieces in place?  That would give everyone a start, and wouldn't leave us guessing at the coordinates.

working on it :)

I assume the error bars are derived from real data and not just arbitrarily drawn. In that case I'd not do this in TikZ. This is something I'd plot in Python's matplotlib (which supports output to pgf or directly to PDF rendered via LaTeX).

You did recognize that pgfplots is dedicated to display data, like for scientific reports, while it is built on Tikz, did you? So I suggest to correct the wording TIKZ in your body and add tag pgfplots ... unless you want to do it all by hand with Tikz ;-)

Hm, can you please give some background information by EDITing your question? E.g. what do the axes mean (NPV, GWI). Are you showing measurement data? What would be the purpose of a box, in fact several overlapping boxes obscuring the plot, i.e. as a visual communicator? So: what do you show and compare, for what purpose? Thank you

Thank you @MS-SPO - I certainly did not recognise it. As a LaTeX beginner (as I consider myself to be) and absolute layman, I am deeply grateful to learn every day from people like you who are willing to help and encourage learning.

@FantasticMsFox If you are anyway manually adding coordinates, you could shade the areas with something like \fill[red,opacity=0.2] (-109.6,12.55) rectangle (606.1,17.65); https://i.sstatic.net/7AX3pNde.png

Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz this is exactly what I wanted.

Here is how you could automatically add confidence intervals: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430650/error-bars-as-shaded-area

Great solution. However you should take the solution part out and answer to yourself. This way we preserve: a) 1 question = exactly 1 problem, b) each answer = 1 specific solution . (Yes, it's a bit different than in chitchat fori, but you'll like it very soon)

Will do @MS-SPO, I am not part of any chitchat forum, so I don't know their practice. I posted an answer and the user called jlab commented I should edit the question instead of posting an answer (which I then deleted again). Anyways, I will edit the question and post the answer separately. Thank you.

Thanks, addressed it below. // Other fori just reply, whatever the content is, often resulting in endless discussions. Here a few comments are fine for clarification, while discussions are discouraged: there are Chatrooms here for this purpose. // The advantage is that this place is very close to a problem-solution almanach.

BTW, to make your question specific, you should copy or undelete your code part to or in the question. It has a valid place both under question and solution.

I made a try doing it manually, resulting in this plot:

..using this code:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                extra x ticks       = 0,
                extra x tick labels = ,
                extra x tick style  = { grid = major },
                height=7cm,
                width=14cm,
                ylabel=GWI,
                xlabel=NPV,
                legend pos=outer north east,
                ]               
                \addplot[CornflowerBlue,mark=*,line width=1pt] plot[error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,y explicit,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                error mark options={
                    rotate=90,
                    mark size=2pt,
                    line width=1pt}
                ]
                coordinates {
                    (-24.8,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (-19.0,9.34)+= (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7) 
                    (-15.3,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (218.4,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7) 
                    (275.3,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (309.7,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (510.8,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (629.0,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                    (700.4,9.34) += (0,1.2) -= (0,0.7)
                };
                \addlegendentry{A}
                \addplot[YellowGreen,mark=*,line width=1pt] plot[error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,y explicit,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                error mark options={
                    rotate=90,
                    mark size=2pt,
                    line width=1pt}
                ]
                coordinates {
                    (-154.1,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (-152.6,16.76) +-(0,2.2) 
                    (-149.4,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (93.80,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (141.7,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (170.9,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (386.2,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (495.4,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                    (561.6,16.76) +-(0,2.2)
                };
                \addlegendentry{B}              
                \addplot[Goldenrod, mark=*,line width=1pt] plot[error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,y explicit,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                error mark options={
                    rotate=90,
                    mark size=2pt,
                    line width=1pt}
                ]
                coordinates {
                    (-204.9,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (-194.5,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0) 
                    (-176.9,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (66.40,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0) 
                    (99.80,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (120.2,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (358.8,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (453.5,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                    (510.8,16.07) += (0,3.2) -= (0,2.0)
                };          
                \addlegendentry{C}
                \addplot[Lavender,mark=*,line width=1pt] plot[error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,y explicit,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                error mark options={
                    rotate=90,
                    mark size=2pt,
                    line width=1pt}
                ]
                coordinates {
                    (-109.6,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (-108.0,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8) 
                    (-105.0,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (138.3,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8) 
                    (186.3,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (215.5,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (430.6,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (540.0,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                    (606.1,14.35) += (0,3.3) -= (0,1.8)
                };
                \addlegendentry{D}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

To get market areas in the respective transparent colours, I added this for each plot (here the example for product A - blue plot):
\fill[CornflowerBlue,opacity=0.3] (-24.8,8.64) rectangle (700.4,10.54); 

The x-values are the minimal and maximum NPV values. The y-values are the respective GWI values with the positive and negative ranges.

Note: The marked areas are only for illustrative purposes and do not add any content-related value.

@jlab, on this site 1 question is intended to be 1 problem (so sometimes OPs are asked to focus more), while each answer is 1 solution. This one is clearly a solution, so a valid answer.

@MS-SPO My comment was on the very first version of the answer, which was deleted and edited. I remove it now.

Right, I recognized later that there was some EDIT-activity going on. My bad, sorry for that.

The answer I deleted was exactly the first part of the answer as it is right now.
